# How to integrate Leaflet into Angular 5

Tags: leaflet, angular5

I've got the standard Angular 5 build and I'm trying to include a Leaflet map. The documentation gives me an error when I follow it. I'm trying to import Leaflet through NPM and include it but I can't find documentation.

I know I need the CSS, ID tag, and imports...

I've downloaded "leaflet" into my "node_modules folder".

Now what? What is the import code for the Leaflet module that I need to put into my "app.module.ts" file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, for better development, install through npm `@types/leaflet` to get leaflet types in application. After that, you need to create component with `Map` property (imported from `leaflet`) and use factory function `map` (also imported from `leaflet`). The most of examples show configuration using `id`, but you can pass `HTMLElement`.

```
constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.map = map(this.element.nativeElement, {...options})
}
```

At this moment, I develop library to integrated leaflet with Angular 5 using components. First stable will be released in next week, but I have first beta release on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-leaflet).

Comment: This was a big help to use in my app.module.ts file: import { Map} from 'leaflet

I also needed to know the following for my compenent.ts file: import * as L from 'leaflet';

Thank you.

Comment: in your component.ts also you can import what you want by import {} from leaflet instead of import all as L.